# Entity Framework Core Re-Seed data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

- *EF Core Version 3.1.4.*
- *SQL Server 2014.*

How do I get EF core to re-seed data after it has been deleted out of the database? It's deleted directly in the database, not through an EF core migration.

My latest migration file has this:

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "Person",
            columns: new[] { "ID", "Name" },
            values: new object[]
            {
                { 1, "Tom Watson" }
            });
```

After running `Update-Database` the Person with ID 1 is created, then someone runs `delete from Person` in SQL Server.  At this point I want to re-seed the data.  Running `Update-Database` does not insert the Person back into the database.

My current solution is to remove my `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasData(...)` code, create a new migration, then add that code back in and create another migration and then finally `Update-Database`.  This is an ugly solution that creates unwanted migrations.

Any ideas? Obviously I can just do an insert on the database, but I'd like to do this through the EF package manager console, as I have a lot more seed data than just this one record.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#initialize-db-with-test-data) you can use seed data like this.

In this case `InitializePersons` is checked every time your program is run, and if there is no record in the database, a new record is saved in the database again.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
            DbInitializer.InitializePersons(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

```cs
public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static void InitializePersons(DbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        context.Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Tom Watson" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```